# How to plot each column of a cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a cell array that looks like this:

```
Column1           Column2
[1 2 3 4]         [2 5 6 9]
[1 3 4]           [3 4 7 8]
[2 3 4]           [1 3 7 9]
[1 2 4]           [1 4 6 8]
```

There are a few more columns that have similar styles of data. I need to create a way to make a graph of each column (separate graphs for each column of the array), that plots each point as a number from each double as the x-coordinate, and the row as the y-coordinate. It should look something like this:

```
(Row)
1 x  x  x  x
2 x     x  x
3    x  x  x
4 x  x     x
  1  2  3  4 
X is just a point on the graph.
```

Does this make enough sense? I feel like I'm making 0 progress in explaining what I want. If anyone doesn't understand this, feel free to ask questions and I'll answer them as best I can.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You are using the column data as the x coordinate and row value as y-coordinate. Am i right?

Comment: That's correct. I want multiple X values for each row (I should be able to draw a vertical line between rows and hit more than 1 point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
cin = { {[1 2 3 4] , [1 3 4], [2 3 4], [1 2 4]}, {[1 2 3 8] , [1 3 4], [2 3 4], [1 2 4]} };

for k=1:numel(cin)
    col_k = cin{k};

    figure();  %// 1 figure per column
    for y=1:numel(col_k)
        plot(col_k{y}, y);
        hold on;
    end    
end
```

Comment: I think I figured out my issue. I was using figure() incorrectly, since I thought you put it equal to the plot command for it to make a new figure. Silly me :) Thanks for all your guys' help!

Comment: never mind it's not working. How can I make this work without adding all the data into one large 1 dimensional array?

Comment: This proposed method for example is not using 1 large array, but a cell array. I can't comment more without knowing on what shape/container your input is.

Comment: the data is formatted as the first post said, with the exception that there are many many other columns.

Comment: But how is the input stored? Are they in different variables, or in a cell array, structure? post an example if you want

Comment: It's a cell array formatted like the above. I'm trying to graph the values in each cell (X) vs. the cell's row (Y)

Comment: This is what the proposed solution does, and it does represent the input also. Post some Matlab code with your input if you need more help

Comment: I changed it up a bit, and added a for loop that encased the rest of the code you provided. After I switched some variables out and added one or two lines it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help :)